# ASIFormDataRequest POST error - iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

I have the following code linked to a PHP file,the objective is to post some strings and retrieve in the PHP file,all the stuff is working fine,but something is wrong with my code,see bellow:

**iOS Application Code**

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myurl.com/path/ios.st.addquestion.php?";
    NSURL *uploadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:uploadURL];

    [request setPostValue:askerUsername forKey:@"username"];
    [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"questiontype"];
    [request setPostValue:title forKey:@"title"];
    [request setPostValue:hasAditional forKey:@"hasaditional"];
    [request setPostValue:aditional forKey:@"aditional"];
    [request setPostValue:hasLocation forKey:@"haslocation"];
    [request setPostValue:location forKey:@"location"];
    [request setPostValue:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
    [request setPostValue:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];
    [request setPostValue:category forKey:@"category"];
    [request setPostValue:hasImage forKey:@"hasimage"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

**PHP File**

```
    $questiontype = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['questiontype']);

    $username_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);

    $title_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
    $hasAditional = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hasaditional']);
    $aditional_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['aditional']);

    $hasLocation = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['haslocation']);
    $location_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['location']);
    $latitude_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['latitude']);
    $longitude_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['longitude']);

    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);

    echo "$username_PRO";
```

When i run the application and POST the strings to the PHP file,nothing happens,is like the PHP received a null value,i can't figure out what is wrong in my code,anyone know?The procedure is something like this:

Application => ASIFormDataRequest(Post values) => **PHP file receives request and insert strings on a MYSQL database(THE PROBLEM IS HERE).**

I have already searched on the web and on ASI website but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you implementing a delegate for the `request`?  If so, perhaps the method `requestFailed:` could provide more clues.  As it is, there's too little information to see where the issue lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code is correct,
however, you POST to PHP and you use $_GET in php might be the problem.

Try to use $_POST to get the POST value or you can dump $_REQUEST to see what have you sent to your php.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `setPostValue` to a `PHP-script` which is looking for `GET` variables. Either change your `PHPcode` to `$username_PRO = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])` for all your varialbes, or send the values as `GET` values with `http://url?name=value&name2=value2` ...